# Shuffling an array bottlenecks on Random.Nex(int)

Tags: c#, arrays, shuffle

I've been working on a small piece of code that sorts the provided array. The array should be sorted as fast as possible. Randomization is not that important. After profiling the method I found out that the biggest hog is `Random.Next`. Which takes up about 70% of the method execution time. After searching online for faster random generators I found no plug and play libraries that offer any improved performance.

So I was wondering whether there are any ways to improve the performance of this code any more.

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private static void Shuffle(byte[] chars)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            var index = rnd.Next(chars.Length);
            byte tmpStore = chars[index];
            chars[index] = chars[i];
            chars[i] = tmpStore;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you pre-JIT everything first.

Comment: Doesn't pre-JITing only help with the startup time of an application? To answer your question, no I did not pre-JIT anything.

Comment: It's not terribly valuable to know that it takes 70% of the execution time. If the total execution is 10ms then who cares? If the total time is 100 hours then also who cares? (In this case you need to re-think the whole algorithm.) But if we know how long it actually takes and how long you want it to take then I think we can offer some help.

Comment: Then you're also measuring the time it takes to JIT the functions.  Call it once before measuring anything.

Comment: @Enigmativity The goal is to reduce the time spent shuffling the array as much as possible.  Since I'm on my phone I don't have the exact execution times available for me. But the fact that 70% of the time is spent on generating a random number is the reason for me to specifically ask about `Random.Next`.

Comment: @SLaks The method is called a significant amount of times during the program execution. So I don't think pre-JITing will have a considerable impact. But I will give it a try, thanks for clarifying it for me!

Comment: @TheDutchDevil - I think you missed my point somewhat and SLaks definitely. For my point, if you could indicate rough times that the code is taking that would be sufficient. SLaks point, if I understood correctly, is that the JITting of the code may have taken most of the time, not the actual execution of the code.

Comment: @Enigmativity This is the first time I'm attempting micro optimizations in C#. So I was wondering if there was any alternative to the .NET random number generator that is more performant. As for pre-JITing, I'm now calling the function once with some dummy data during application startup. But that doesn't have any considerable impact on the time spent executing the function.

Comment: @TheDutchDevil - Can you not give us the actual time taken for the current algorithm?

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry for the delay. It takes about 262 nanoseconds for one shuffle of an array with 16 elements.

Comment: @TheDutchDevil - 262ns? 0.262ms? Unless you have some other set of data that you're expecting to process you should move on. This is exceptionally quick. Why are you worried about this performance?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this is getting into micro-optimization territory.

`Random.Next(int)` actually performs some ops internally that we can optimize out:

```
int index = (int)(rnd.Next() * (1.0 / int.Max) * chars.Length);
```

Since you're using the same `maxValue` over and over in a loop, a trivial optimization would be to precalculate your denominator outside of the loop. This way we get rid of an `int`->`double` conversion and a multiply:

```
double d = chars.Length / (double)int.Max;
```

And then:

```
int index = (int)(rnd.Next() * d);
```

**On a separate note:** your shuffle isn't going to have a uniform distribution. See Jeff Atwood's post *[The Danger of Naïveté](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/)* which deals specifically with this subject and shows how to perform a uniform Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Wow. I'm thoroughly astounded by the results in Jeff Atwood's post. That blew me away. I'm still trying to get my head around it.

Comment: BTW, I did a test of the OP's sort, the KFY sort from the article, and this sort - `source.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())`. The OP's suffers from non-uniform distribution, but the other approaches don't.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! This method yielded the best performance increase so far. It still bottlenecks on generating the random number but at least it's a little bit faster now. Would you have any ideas on how to improve the speed of the random generation? @Enigmativity I can image that `source.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())` uses a KFY sort.

Comment: Note that a KFY shuffle is O(n), while a sort or `OrderBy` will be O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

If `n^n` isn't too big for the double range, you could create one random double number, multiply it by `n^n`, then use  `modulo(n)` each iteration as the current random number prior to dividing the random result by n as preparation for the next iteration.

Comment: Using this does not yield any improvements. Even though less time is spent generating random number the calculations that are done appear to take up as much time as the random number generation takes.